# How can you programmatically trigger the "numbers / symbols" view for the Apple standard keyboard?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uikeyboard

I have a textField that I pre-populate with text by setting the `text` property.

What I would like to achieve is if the last character of the text that I am setting is a number, I would like to have the keyboard automatically be on the symbols and numbers view once the textField becomes the firstResponder.

To be clear, I do NOT want to change the textField's `keyboardType` property and only present a numPad. What I want to achieve is to be able to programmatically toggle the normal alphanumeric keyboard to the numbers  / symbols view that shows up when you tap the `123` key (next to space bar) on the bottom left of the alphabet view of the keyboard.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Setting the keyboardType to `numbersAndPunctuation` still lets the user switch back to the alphabetic keyboard.

Comment: I know you're not supposed to say thank you -- but THANK YOU